# How to easily make asyn/await works with the traditional callback function in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

As we know, ES6 give us a great solution for callback hell， but how to handle the source which already wrote withe call back?
I don't want to rewrite those code, just want to get a easy way to make it works.

Comment: *just want to get a easy way to make it works* - you could start with posting your code instead of making users guess what exactly you meant. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code-related SO questions.

Answer (score -1):

1. A helper function

   function promise(this_obj, func, ...restArgs) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       restArgs.push((err,result)=>{
           if(err){
               reject(err);
           }else{
               resolve(result);
           }
       });
       func.apply (this_obj, restArgs);
    });
   }
2. Before

   ```
    redis.hget("k1", "k2", function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
       reject(err);
     } else {
       resolve(result);
     }
   });
   ```
3. Now

   var result = await promise(redis, redis.hget, "k1", "k2");

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. There's `util.promisify` that serves this purpose.